# Nested tabhost fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have an application with 3 screens, each screen is a fragment. I want that in 1 screen there will be 2 other screens.
for example:

```
| TAB 1 | TAB 2 | TAB 3 |
```

now when you are in TAB 1

you will see

```
| INNER_TAB 1 | INNER_TAB 2 |
```

This is how I tried to implement it:

1. Main Activity which extends FragmentActivity
2. I have 3 Fragments  (classes) - one for each tab
3. In the MainActivity I added the tabs into the tab host.
4. I tried to create that one Fragment from step 2 will extend FragmentActivity, so I could add inner
   tabs to this fragment.
5. Everything is compile as well.
6. Run the application and press the first tab to see the inner tabs and - exception - can't cast 
   fragmentActivity to fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while I came with a solution.

As I said each fragment has its own class and layout, so in Tab1 layout I added FragmentTabHost.
And in onCreateView method of Tab1 I initializing the FragmentTabHost and adding the inner tabs for it.

Comment: Hey, I'm having this same problem, any chance you can upload some sample code?